# simple_form add label to Collection Radio Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, label, simple-form

I have the following code:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :access_type_id, AccessType.all, :id, :name, group_label_method: 'Access type' %>
```

and it gives me:

[image]

using the following HTML:

```
<fieldset>
...
  <span>
    <label for="log_file_access_type_id_1" name="log_file[access_type_id]">
      <input id="log_file_access_type_id_1" name="log_file[access_type_id]" type="radio" value="1">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="log_file_access_type_id_1">
        public
      </label>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <label for="log_file_access_type_id_2" name="log_file[access_type_id]">
      <input id="log_file_access_type_id_2" name="log_file[access_type_id]" type="radio" value="2">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="log_file_access_type_id_2">
        protected
      </label>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <label for="log_file_access_type_id_3" name="log_file[access_type_id]">
      <input id="log_file_access_type_id_3" name="log_file[access_type_id]" type="radio" value="3">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="log_file_access_type_id_3">
        private
      </label>
    </label>
  </span>
...
</fieldset>
```

I want to add `label` for the radio buttons group. I have try using `group_label_method: 'Access type'` but nothing changed.

Is there a way to add such label using `simple_form` methods or I should just added as plain HTML?

Answer (score 2):

try this

simple form http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_radio_buttons

```
 collection_radio_buttons(:access_type_id, AccessType.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b|
   b.label(:"data-value" => b.value) { b.radio_button + b.text }
 end
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined method `name_with_initial' for #<AccessType:0x00000006298f28>`

Comment: @gotqn thats because that is not a method callable on your `AccessType` model. you could just use `:name`. This snippet was copied from the docs for `collection_radio_buttons`

Comment: Where do you put this, in the haml?